# Entity Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Хочу сделать резюме с бекенд, которое я буду заполнять через веб приложение. У меня есть основной enitity Resume. И еще 5 разных entity:Education, Skills, Profile, Summary, Language. Они простые с id, name и тд полями. Но видимо я что-то делаю не правильно или в них, или в ентити Resume:

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Resume {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "resume")
    private Set<Education> educations;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "resume")
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "resume")
    private Set<Language> languages;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "summary_id")
    private Summary summary;

   //contructor without id
}
```

hardcode в базу данных:

```java
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Set<Education> educations = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Language> languages = new HashSet<>();

        Education e1 = new Education("asd", "asd");
        Education e2 = new Education("asd asd", "asd");
        Skill s1 = new Skill("Java", 3);
        Skill s2 = new Skill("SQL", 1);
        Skill s3 = new Skill("JavaScript", 2);
        Profile profile = new Profile("asd", "asd", "asd",
                "asd","asd", "github.com", "asd");
        Language l1 = new Language("asd");
        Language l2 = new Language("asd");
        Summary summary = new Summary("I am good at Java");


        educations.add(e1);
        educations.add(e2);
        skills.add(s1);
        skills.add(s2);
        skills.add(s3);
        languages.add(l1);
        languages.add(l2);
        Resume resume = new Resume(educations, skills, profile, languages, summary);

        educationRepository.saveAll(educations);
        skillRepository.saveAll(skills);
        languageRepository.saveAll(languages);
        profileRepository.save(profile);
        summaryRepository.save(summary);
        resumeRepository.save(resume);
    }
```

получаю такую ошибку:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ua.korzh.resume.education.Education.resume in ua.korzh.resume.cv.Resume.educations
```

и

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ua.korzh.resume.education.Education.resume in ua.korzh.resume.cv.Resume.educations
```

Comment: Приведите код entity:Education

Comment: просто Long id; String name; constructors, getters, setters.

Comment: Ну так он на это и ругается mappedBy = "resume", в нем должна быть ссылка на резюме, а ее нет, как я понял